# How to save the webform data to custom table?

Tags: 8, forms, database, webforms

I designed a student registration form using webforms module. My requirement is to save data from the form to table student. How can i achieve this? Is there anyway to mention this in configuration file?

Comment: The webform data is already saver om the DB. To save it in a custom table you must implement a hook that updates your custom table when the web form is submitted.

Comment: You can do custom saving of data with Webform Handlers. A tutorial can be found here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-create-mailchimp-subscription-drupal-8-webform-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom submit handler to your Webform through `hook_form_alter` for inserting it's data into your custom table.

To achieve it check the below example.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form['#form_id'] == "YOUR_WEBFORM"){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION';
  }
}

function YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(&$form, $form_state){
  $query = Database::getConnection();
  $query->insert('YOUR_CUSTOM_TABLE_NAME')->fields(
    array(
      'FIELD_NAME_IN_TABLE' => $form_state->getValue('FIELD_NAME_IN_FORM'),
    )
  )->execute();
}
```